# creating a new dictionary out of 2 matching ones

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable

```
 labelMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
 branchLineMap = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

if one key of the first dictionary matches another key of the other dictionary then I need to make a new dictionary with the value of branchlineMap to become the key and the value of LabelMap to become the value. How do I do this while iterating over the whole dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods, you can do it like this:

```
var newDictionary = labelMap
                   .Where(x => branchLineMap.ContainsKey(x.Key))
                   .ToDictionary(x => branchLineMap[x.Key], x => x.Value);
```

Comment: it seems like you are just storing the variable of just one match rather than creating a new dictionary with all the matches.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the two, using LINQ.

Query syntax:

```
var newDict = (from b in branchLineMap
               join l in labelMap on b.Key equals l.Key
               select new { b = b.Value, l = l.Value })
              .ToDictionary(x => x.b, x => x.l);
```

Same thing, using method syntax:

```
var newDict = branchLineMap.Join(labelMap, b => b.Key, l => l.Key,
                                 (b, l) => new { b = b.Value, l = l.Value })
                           .ToDictionary(x => x.b, x => x.l);
```